# Why is my 'data' register variable resetting to 0 once testbench gets into the fr_count conditional block?

Tags: verilog, fpga

[Here is my module in question](https://pastebin.com/s0uQ3ci7), and when I set my break point to the first line under (if fr_count == 20million), I can scroll over the 'data' register and 'data_store' register and they both read as 0. I need them to properly set mailbox and prev_mailbox registers, but for some reason they are resetting as if they're being assigned by blocking assignments as soon as this conditional block starts executing.

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

I have tried commenting out the only lines where I do reset the registers to 0 but they still insist on resetting.

Am I wrong expecting the results to reset at the end of the posedge clk block? The only lines where it's being reset are non-blocking assignments:

`data <= 0;`
and
`data_store <= 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning values to both data and data_store in two different always blocks. That is a big NO NO!!

Except under special circumstances (e.g. tri-state signals) you must assign a value only from one always block. (or from one  `assign...`)

It can not be synthesized: You will get a synthesis warning.

It will work in behavioral code and you can simulate it, but leads to race conditions or other unwanted phenomena, as you have noticed.